# Add a number in random rows in Excel

Tags: excel, random, numbers

I have a Excel that have 780 rows with data.
I like to add in one column (D) a number but I like to add it random rows and only 15 of them so if the row already have a number is going to find another one that does not have any.

It is for a game that I going to do and the number I going to add is week numbers (1-52) so each week I going to have 15 question.

Comment: show this starting code

Comment: 780 = 52*15. Is you goal to have each number in the range 1-52 repeated exactly 15 times?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to do this once and for all, you can do the following:

Step 1: Put the numbers 1 to 780 in column D (say starting at D1)

Step 2: Put the formual `=1+MOD(D1,52)` in E1 and copy down

Step 3: Copy column E and (using paste-special) paste it onto column D *as values*. Now delete column E.

At this stage column D contains the values 1-52, each repeated 15 times.

Step 4: Put the formula `=RAND()` in E1 and copy down

Step 5: Highlight columns D and E and sort them *according to column E*.

Step 6: Delete column E.

The trick of creating a column of random numbers and then sorting according to it is a nice way to randomly permute rows

Comment: Thanks for the replay but have problem with step 2. it say something is wrong with the formual

Comment: @Cazz The formula in step 2 is perfectly valid. If your numbers in column D start in e.g. the second row then of course this formula would need to be in E2 and be adjusted accordingly.

Comment: @Cazz Perhaps you were having trouble with the mechanics of entering formulas. There should only be one = sign, not 2 (one automatically put there by Excel when entering a formula from the formula bar and one typed by you). I am only guessing since you neglected to say what the error message said.

Comment: @Cazz Also, I think that some regional settings might expect a semicolon ; rather than a comma , in the formula

Comment: You have make me a very happy person. Thanks alot
The problem was that Microsoft have rename MOD to REST and RAND to SLUMP (swedish word)